# Best Practice in handling comparator

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, compareto

How to handle null objects, which comes in compareTo method. This always causes nullpointer exception. What a is best way to solve this issue.

Comment: avoid comparing to null objects?

Comment: It comes in collection while iterating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int compareTo(Object to) {
  if (to == null) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  // Now knowing it's not null, continue as before
}
```

Comment: This will not help if you are using `null.compareTo(object)` - which should give the inverse result for asymmetry reasons.

Comment: Do you have a solution, too? As far as I can tell, it's not possible to do.

Comment: With `compareTo`, no. **Don't put `null` in a collection which you want to sort.** With `Comparator.compare(x,y)` you can use this, but you should make sure it stays well-defined (most easily if `null` is either smaller or greater than all non-null elements).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the object before you call "compareTo" method.

like this:

```
if(obj != null){

  //TODO  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the fine documentation on [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.

Don't put null in a sorted collection if you don't want to handle NullPointerExceptions.